# Why use cocoapods at all?

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods, dependency-management, carthage

I have been trying to use cocoapods for a few apps and every single time it just screws up my frameworks, I find it much simpler to just drag a framework in and use it straight away. And completely removing cocoa pods is such a mess too!

I cannot for the life of me understand why people consider cocoapods to be an acceptable solution for any kind of app.

I don't know maybe I'm not using it the correct way, but why do we need dependency managers in general?

I have used Carthage and it seems to be a far superior alternative, something which gives you frameworks without messing around with your Xcode project!

Comment: Now before anybody decides to downvote, at least have an educated discussion about this rather than getting all butthurt about somebodies (unprofessional) opinion!

Comment: "why do we need dependency managers in general" Carthage is a dependency managers, no?

Comment: Cocoapods is for people that think there cool.  Totally agree,  simply drag it in.